# How can I hide fields in new user registration form in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I hide form fields in the Wordpress 'new user registration' form located in wp-admin/user-new.php?
I want to hide the fields with ID's 'first_name' and 'last_name' since I'm building a plug-in.

I've already made a extending part for this form. But I want to hide fields from the original form.
The reason I want to do this is because in the Netherlands we have a lastname_prefix like 'Mike van den Hoek' where 'van den' is the prefix. I want to place the fields for 'first_name', 'lastname_prefix' and 'last_name' in to the extending part of this form and not in the orginal form.

I tried to this with the jQuery function `hide()` and give this function the ID of the form field I want to hide. But unfortunate this doesn't work.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what didn't work. Also read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please paste the following code in your plugin php file.

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'remove_first_name_and_last_name');
function remove_first_name_and_last_name() { 
global $pagenow;
    if ($pagenow !='user-new.php') return;
echo '<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".user-new-php #first_name, .user-new-php #last_name").parent().parent().hide();
});
</script>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmudul this works perfectly.
What does: .user-new-php mean in the jquery script exactly?

Comment: .user-new-php is the body class of 'Add New User' page. So it will hide 'first_name' and 'last_name' only on ''Add New User' page'.